# How are professional "instrumental" soundtracks created?

Tags: sound-design, sound, building-a-soundtrack

I would like to know how professional instrumental soundtracks and sounds for movies or other types of media are generally created. Here is a soundtrack from a video game in which I am specifically interested.

(From 3:28 to 4:08)

I would like to know how this kind of soundtrack is created, but I am not sure what kind of genre it is or what category of soundtracks it would go under.

I am looking for an answer that can point out the name of the category or genre that kind of soundtrack would go under. I am also looking for a professional answer telling me how these kinds of soundtracks are generally created. I know I might seem a bit too vague, but I am trying to express my question as best as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of cinematic sound used to require a lot of paper, a lot of people & a large studio to hold them all - in other words a composer, a conductor & an orchestra; plus all the technicians to accurately capture their performance.

These days, it can be done to quite a convincing degree using large sample libraries & a DAW.
The leaders in this in recent times were [audiobro](http://audiobro.com), with their LASS [LA Scoring Strings] library; though in any field of this type there is always going to be the new guy trying to out-do the existing exponents & in recent years [Spitfire Audio](https://www.spitfireaudio.com) have made some quite stunning libraries of their own; Albion & the BML [British Modular Library] have been game-changers in the field.

One thing to note - the prices on this type of library are not for the casual amateur, or indeed the faint of heart - even if they have been falling in recent times. You're still looking at a grand or two to really get started.

After that, all you need to supply is a good DAW & a fair bit of tenacity - not to mention a fair bit of talent ;-)

Comment: +1 I recently noticed that the soundtrack to the series "Dark Matter" is both pretty good and sounds less expensive. Almost like the entire thing could be done with NI Massive. Certainly the best sounding libraries come at a premium price, and at the same time the quality of the composition will always be the most important aspect of any music.

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for! Thanks for the valuable information! I was always interested in knowing the creation process of these kinds of soundtracks.